# Airflow parallelism based on operator type

Tags: airflow

Does airflow support throttling or parallelism limit by operator type.
I want to limit number of spark submits across different dags but not end up limiting the parallelism across

Comment: see cluster policy https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#task-level-cluster-policy

Answer (score 1):

You want to use an Airflow `pool`. See for details: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#pools.

In short, what a `pool` does is limit the number of available slots for tasks to run in. In your case, you can subclass the operators in question and give them a default pool parameter of a particular pool instance so that developers are nudged in the correct direction.